# Is there a way to load the headers from a CSV into a table to compare to the headers that are already in the system?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, csv

I am trying to load two CSV files. One is the standard for the system and the other is the one that we want to import. I am trying to create a table where one side shows the standard and the other has a drop down list of the CSV being imported. Showing the standard is not too difficult but need some help in loading the new CSV file and need to map the new CSV to the standard and then create a new file with the information in the correct fields.

This is for Javascript and ReactJS. I have not been able to discover a way to do this yet and would love some help in figuring this out.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import ReactFileReader from 'react-file-reader';

export default class TableMap extends Component {
    state = {
        iGorMap: [


            {
                "FiduciaryOutsourcingField": "ID",
                "YourField": ""
            },
            {
                "FiduciaryOutsourcingField": "CreateDate",
                "YourField": ""
            },
            {
                "FiduciaryOutsourcingField": "UpdateDate",
                "YourField": ""
            },
            {
                "FiduciaryOutsourcingField": "RecordStatus",
                "YourField": ""
            },
            {
                "FiduciaryOutsourcingField": "Source",
                "YourField": ""
            },
            {
                "FiduciaryOutsourcingField": "SourceId",
                "YourField": ""
            },
            {
                "FiduciaryOutsourcingField": "BatchNumber",
                "YourField": ""
            },
            {
                "FiduciaryOutsourcingField": "CompletedStages",
                "YourField": ""
            },
            {
                "FiduciaryOutsourcingField": "EIN",
                "YourField": ""
            },
            {
                "FiduciaryOutsourcingField": "Location",
                "YourField": ""
            },

        ]
    }

    // renderSelectedDropdown() {
    //     return this.state.
    // }
    renderDropdownValues() {
        handleFiles = files => {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = e => {
                // Use reader.result
                this.setState({
                    csvData: reader.result
                });
            };
            reader.readAsText(files[0]);
            console.log(reader);
        };
        function convertJson(csvData) {
            var temp = csvData.split("\n");
            var temp2 = temp[0].split(",");
            return temp2;
        }

        var mappedFromCsv = convertJson(csvData);

        // var mappedFromCsv = Object.keys(this.state.temp2)
        //console.log(header)
        return mappedFromCsv.map((key, index) => {
            return <option value={index}>{key}</option>
            // return <th className="tableHeader" key={index}>{key}</th>
        })
    }
    renderTableData() {
        return this.state.iGorMap.map((iGorMap, index) => {
            const { FiduciaryOutsourcingField, YourField } = iGorMap 
            return (
                <tr key={FiduciaryOutsourcingField}>
                    <td>{FiduciaryOutsourcingField}</td>
                    <td>
                        <div className="dropdown" role="combobox" >
                            <select class="browser-default custom-select">
                                <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                                {this.renderDropdownValues()}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr >
            )
        })
    }
    renderTableHeader() {
        let header = Object.keys(this.state.iGorMap[0])
        return header.map((key, index) => {
            return <th className="tableHeader" key={index}>{key}</th>
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ReactFileReader
                    multipleFiles={false}
                    fileTypes={[".csv"]}
                    handleFiles={this.handleFiles}
                >
                    <button type='button' className="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
                </ReactFileReader>
                <Table bordered hover striped>

                    <thead className="thead-dark" id="top">
                        {this.renderTableHeader()}
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.renderTableData()}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        )
    }

};
```

Comment: Sorry for the code format problem tried to fix it but wasnt able to find a way to have it all in the code screen.

Comment: Thanks @derpirscher for fixing my code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured it out. I needed to create the state and then set that state.

```
import React, {
  Component
} from "react";
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
import ReactFileReader from "react-file-reader";
import Papa from "papaparse";

export default class TableMap extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      //? standard Mapping for dataSet
      iGorMap: [{
          FiduciaryOutsourcingField: "ID",
          YourField: ""
        },
        {
          FiduciaryOutsourcingField: "CreateDate",
          YourField: ""
        },
        {
          FiduciaryOutsourcingField: "UpdateDate",
          YourField: ""
        },
        {
          FiduciaryOutsourcingField: "RecordStatus",
          YourField: ""
        }
      ],
      //*for options dropdown
      dropOpt: []
    };
  }

  //* This method gets the keys from dropOpt and then puts the key in each option in the dropdown
  renderDropdownValues() {
    return this.state.dropOpt.map((key, index) => {
      return ( <
        option key = {
          index
        }
        id = {
          index
        } > {
          key
        } <
        /option>
      );
    });
  }

  //* handleFiles transforms the incoming CSV sheet and returns the header from the first row
  handleFiles = files => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var parseConfig = {
      delimiter: "", // auto-detect
      newline: "", // auto-detect
      quoteChar: '"',
      escapeChar: '"',
      header: true,
      transformHeader: undefined,
      dynamicTyping: false,
      preview: 0,
      encoding: "",
      worker: false,
      comments: false,
      step: undefined,
      complete: undefined,
      error: undefined,
      download: false,
      skipEmptyLines: true,
      chunk: undefined,
      fastMode: undefined,
      beforeFirstChunk: undefined,
      withCredentials: undefined,
      transform: undefined,
      delimitersToGuess: [",", "\t", "|", ";", Papa.RECORD_SEP, Papa.UNIT_SEP]
    };

    //* All configuration options for "unparsing" JSON back to CSV
    //TODO: unparseConfig not currently used will need to use in full production.
    // var unparseConfig = {
    //   quotes: false, //or array of booleans
    //   quoteChar: '"',
    //   escapeChar: '"',
    //   delimiter: ",",
    //   header: true,
    //   newline: "\n",
    //   skipEmptyLines: true, //or 'greedy',
    //   columns: null //or array of strings
    // };

    //* reads incoming CSV file within the browser and parses the header of the first row
    reader.onload = e => {
      var fileIn = reader.result;
      var fileInParsed = fileIn.replace(/(00\/00\/0000)/g, ""); // Removing 00/00/00 dates
      var csvData = Papa.parse(fileInParsed, parseConfig);

      //* csvData.data is the grouping of Objects
      var dataJson = csvData.data;
      var jsonKeys = Object.keys(dataJson[0]);
      // console.log(dataJson[0]); //for debugging
      // console.log(csvData.data.length); //for debugging
      // console.log(jsonKeys); //for debugging

      //* breaks out the key and index of the jsonKeys array
      return jsonKeys.map((key, index) => {
        // console.log("I got here"); //for debugging
        // console.log(key, index); //for debugging
        return this.setState({
          dropOpt: jsonKeys
        });
      });
    };
    reader.readAsText(files[0]);
  };

  //* displays the data for the table
  renderTableData() {
    return this.state.iGorMap.map((key, index) => {
      const {
        FiduciaryOutsourcingField
      } = key; //destructuring
      return ( <
        tr key = {
          index
        } >
        <
        td key = {
          index
        }
        id = {
          index
        } > {
          FiduciaryOutsourcingField
        } <
        /td> <
        td >
        <
        div className = "dropdown"
        role = "combobox"
        aria - controls = "ex1-listbox"
        aria - expanded = "false" >
        <
        select className = "browser-default custom-select" > {
          this.renderDropdownValues()
        } <
        /select> <
        /div> <
        /td> <
        /tr>
      );
    });
  }
  renderTableHeader() {
    let header = Object.keys(this.state.iGorMap[0]);
    return header.map((key, index) => {
      return ( <
        th className = "tableHeader"
        key = {
          index
        } > {
          key
        } <
        /th>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      ReactFileReader multipleFiles = {
        false
      }
      fileTypes = {
        [".csv"]
      }
      handleFiles = {
        this.handleFiles
      } >
      <
      button type = "button"
      className = "btn btn-success" >
      Upload <
      /button> <
      /ReactFileReader> <
      Table bordered hover striped >
      <
      thead className = "thead-dark"
      id = "top" >
      <
      tr > {
        this.renderTableHeader()
      } < /tr> <
      /thead> <
      tbody > {
        this.renderTableData()
      } < /tbody> <
      /Table> <
      /div>
    );
  }
}
```